# merging spring with Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, spring-mvc

What is spring? Why is it being usd with Hibernate? What`s it`s utility?

Answer (score 0):

> > What is spring?

[Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) is an object container and DI framework among others. It is a port of the popular Java Spring framework to .NET.

> > Why is it being usd with Hibernate?

Because it brings AOP functionalities that simplify the session management.

> > Whats its utility?

It avoids you writing some common recurring code but of course this will depend on what modules you use.